# Maven project for Spring Boot error during gitlab CD deployment on heroku

Tags: spring, heroku, gitlab

I want to deploy spring boot application on heroku using CI/CD gitlab pipline.
This is my yaml file.

```
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - production

variables:
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.m2"
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "-s .m2/settings.xml --batch-mode"
  POSTGRES_DB: test
  POSTGRES_USER: postgres
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres

.only-default: &only-default
  only:
    - develop
    - merge_requests
    - tags

build-app:
...

unit-tests:
...

integration-tests:
...

build-preprod-package:
  image: maven:latest
  stage: production
  script:
      - cd source_code
      - mvn package -P preprod
  only:
      - master

preprod:
  type: deploy
  stage: production
  image: ruby:latest
  script:
      - apt-get update -yq
      - apt-get install -y ruby-dev
      - gem install dpl
      - dpl --provider=heroku --app=$HEROKU_APP_PRODUCTION --api-key=$HEROKU_API_KEY
  only:
      - master
```

This is my project structure.
[image]

I added buildpack on heroku https://github.com/heroku/heroku-maven-plugin.git
During the execution of CD process I receive error message.

```
App not compatible with buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-maven-plugin.git
```

Comment: "No default language could be detected for this app"—this is a problem with your application's source code. It has nothing to do with GitLab CI. Please [edit] your question and show your directory structure.

Comment: @Chris directory structure you are referring to maven project structure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due to invalid buildpack for maven with jdk 11 on Heroku.